# org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Type interface com.seaway.xx.xxx.xxxr is not known to the MapperRegistry

Tags: spring, mybatis

My question is like this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732636/mybatis-3-spring-mvc-type-interface-is-not-known-to-the-mapperregistry), but I wrote the implementation of the mapper.

When I use eclipse, there is no problem, but in idea, the problem persists.

This is my structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem is idea can't compile xml under src/main/java. so you can set this directory as a resource directory on idea modules->sources.

if this directory contains .java files and .xml files,like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI1Cj.png),you should add some code into pom.xml of maven.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```